# How to run algorithms within elki-tutorial-0.7.0.jar?

Tags: java, classpath, elki

I can run elki's algorithm with command like this:

```
java -jar elki-bundle-0.7.1.jar
```

But how to run algorithms within elki-tutorial-0.7.0.jar?

Comment: Who and why -1 without any explanation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add all jars you want to the classpath:

```
java -cp elki-bundle-0.7.1.jar:elki-tutorial-0.7.0.jar de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.application.ELKILauncher
```

If you have all jars in a folder `jars`, then

```
java -cp "jars/*" de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.application.ELKILauncher
```

If you use `-cp`, you need to give the main class with full class name. With `-jar` (which only supports a single jar), the class name is in the jar.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add it to your **Java classpath**.